# Why people of Zion have been oblivious of fate of the previous Zion?

Tags: the-matrix

I wonder why none of the previous Ones have not informed the founders of new Zion that there had been another Zion previously and that Matrix still have them.

I think that such knowledge may be of crucial value for the resistance. I know it may be devastating for their morale, but hiding the information also may be seen as an act of treason as it is basically handing the newly found enclave to the enemy.

[EDIT]

According to answers to [Is the last "One" present at the re-founding of Zion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/80603/is-the-last-one-present-at-the-re-founding-of-zion), The One has a possibility to inform them as he meets them in person.

[EDIT2]

I know The One is given no choice but to accept the offer to reestablish Zion as the current Zion is to be wiped out and he is unable to prevent it.

What I am asking is why is he complying to his role as real-world agent of The Matrix? Why is he loyal to it instead trying to defect in any way?

Comment: Because the ones that were selected by the previous The One from within the Matrix have no knowledge of Zion other than what they're told (e.g. that it's out there somewhere). By the time they "find it" again (after a convenient amount of time wandering in the wilderness), the machines have removed all trace of the former inhabitants.

Comment: I strongly suspect given the size and scale of Zion that it's the same city *each time*. There simply isn't the time or the manpower for them to have built it from scratch.

Comment: @Valorum that is exactly what I am asking about: why The One hides that knowledge from them?

Comment: Because it's his job to do so.

Comment: @Valorum you may answer every question like that: "it is what he does". Please see the edit #2.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the choice the Architect gives Neo; if he does not comply with setting up Zion and the next cycle to stabilize the system, the Machines are willing to deal with the problem of humans by eliminating the problem entirely, even if it means difficulties for them. Not just the people of Zion would be killed: *all* humans would be.

A One who has made the choice to save humanity from genocide by agreeing to cooperate isn't likely to do something that would then cause that genocide.

Comment: It is definitively why the One accepted the offer, but after new Zion is started, the machines have no way to verify whether the One is following the non-disclosure part of agreement.
Thus he may either inform every "free" human on what is going on, or inform only Zion leader/council, or establish a kind of order keeping that information for the next One, etc.

Comment: To what end? The One has accepted that there's no way for the humans to win. What's he going to tell them? "So guys, just so you know, this whole thing is bullshit and at some point everyone is going to die, so...congratulations on escaping the Matrix!"

Comment: with the alternative being making them unaware slaughter animals? I would go with something like "the machines know exact location of Zion and when Zion reaches certain degree of development, they are going to wipe it out, so you must take it into account when planning your long-term strategy".

Comment: Because that's just trying to upset the system, when it's already established that a One who agrees with the Architect is *not* trying to upset the system; indeed the One is actively choosing to maintain the system because upsetting the system results in human genocide. It's a needs of the many/needs of the few situation. Zion's people are a necessary sacrifice in order to keep the rest of humanity alive.